# Language specific files in forgeRock

Tags: openam, forgerock

I have a custom login page in my application which gets redirected to openAM. On the login page the content comes based on the locale. I am unable to figure out where exactly the language specific translations for the content are coming from. My Login.jsp and other such JSP pages are placed at the below location--
**/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/openam/config/auth/default/services/'my_brand'/html**
If someone can guide me and tell where exactly the translations come from that would be great. I also had one more doubt regarding the values of below content--

```
ID <jato:text name="htmlTitle_Login" />
```

Where exactly do we find the value of '**htmlTitle_Login**'. I actually wanted to change the values of few of these tags and language specific content but am unable to find the location of the files from where the value comes from.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the

> amAuthUI

resource boundle.